# Linux Oracle - Random crash CPU Stuck

Tags: kernel, crash, oracle-linux

I have several Linux oracle VMs running under hyper-V. Kernel version is `2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64`.

Sometimes, the VM stuck, we still can ping it, but we cannot ssh, or through the hyper-v console this is what I can see :

```
BUG: soft lockup - CPU#1 stuck for 67s! [sshd:9949]
```

Google tell me that this should be a kernel bug, and update should fix.  I must say that I really don't know where to go with this ...
Ask for more details or info if needed.